# MySQL: declare output as 'null' but returns '0'

Tags: mysql, parameters, null, case

I am writing a procedure that uses cases. One of the cases is that if the parameter is null, then the output message should say 'null'. But when I tested it, it's not doing that! Instead, I'm getting the output message as '0'.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Here is some of the code:

```
    If count_cl_id is null then
        set v_msg := 'null';
    Elseif count_cl_id = 1 then
        set v_msg := 1;
    Elseif count_cl_id = 0 then
        set v_msg := 0;
    End if;
```

Comment: How about showing us the code?

Comment: Also, if I leave the v_msg := 'null' as just null (without quotes), I still get 0. And I still got v_msg as 0

Comment: @user1682055 are you doing it inside procedure or function?

Comment: @user1682055 ok.. can you show the whole code?

Comment: Is `v_msg` declared as a char or int?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a scoping problem, which would be the issue if you're trying to examine v_msg is a different BEGIN/END block.  Check [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/local-variable-scope.html).